# making two animations at once in A-frame

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe

For example, by using camera rig, I want to move from A to B then B to C in just one single click. I normally write "to 0 0 0" in the event "onclick".

I want trigger both animations "1" and "1_1". At the moment it is only the "1_1" that is triggered by a click. I'm using a timeline from https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-timeline-component

My code can be found in https://glitch.com/edit/#!/winter-deserted-topaz

Comment: You want to chain two animations one after another, or play two animations at the same time?

Comment: Chain two animations one after the other, But it is also nice to know how to play two animations at the same time. I did experiment with "delay" but it was not working well. Onclick event seems working only on single animation as well. 

I assume that it would be flexible enough if I know how to trigger "animation-timeline" so I can add several animations in "animation-group".

Comment: I tested the second code version https://glitch.com/edit/#!/chartreuse-stellar-paw

I cleaned up a a bit. I forgot to add animation-timeline component javascript. Now the animation timeline seems working. But the new code created a new problem: autoplay. I want to get the onclick event and non-autoplay back as in the first code.

Comment: Solved it by adding "startEvents: myTimeline". Though I dont understand as when I click again and the object goes back and forth. How to disable it once the animation is completed? Alternatively I add invisible object behind the object to disable any further click. Another solution. :D

Comment: According to the manual, the word "animationtimelinecomplete" has to be added in Event section (emitted when animation timeline is complete. Event detail contains animation name (__<ID>). Im not sure what kind of code to write?

Comment: I thought it would be best if i wrote a as-simple-as-possible example, let me know if it helps (i can add one with the animation-timeline component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic is general, so I'll split it into separate cases:

1. **Firing two simultaneous animations**

   If the animation components within an entity share an event ( defined in [startEvents](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#api_startevents) ) they will all fire at once:

   ```html
       <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
       <a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
         <a-box position="0 1 -3" rotation="0 45 0" scale="0.25 0.25 0.25" color="#4CC3D9" 

         animation__rotation="property: rotation; from: 0 45 0; to: 0 405 0; dur: 4000; 
         easing: linear; startEvents: click" 

         animation__scale="property: scale; from: 0.25 0.25 0.25; to: 1.5 1.5 1.5; dur: 2000; 
         dir: alternate; easing: linear; loop: 2; startEvents: click">
         </a-box>
       </a-scene>
   ```
2. **Starting an animation after another one is finished**

   You can wait for one animation to finish and start another one with a bit of javascript.

   You can determine if an animation has ended with the [animationcomplete__](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#events)(ID is the 'name' string after the *animation__* bit) event.

   Then you can emit a signal, which starts the second animation:

   ```html
       <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
       <script>
         AFRAME.registerComponent("animation-manager", {
           init: function() {
             // wait for the first animation to finish
             this.el.addEventListener("animationcomplete__first", e => {
               // start the second animation
               this.el.emit("second")
             })
           }
         })
       </script>
       <a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
         <a-box position="0 1 -3" rotation="0 45 0" scale="0.25 0.25 0.25" animation-manager color="#4CC3D9" 
         animation__first="property: rotation; from: 0 45 0; to: 0 405 0; dur: 2000; 
         easing: linear; startEvents: click" 
         animation__second="property: scale; from: 0.25 0.25 0.25; to: 1.5 1.5 1.5; dur: 2000; 
         dir: alternate; easing: linear; loop: 2; startEvents: second">
         </a-box>
       </a-scene>
   ```