# How to make an entity complete two rotations in one animation

Tags: aframe

```
<a-mixin id="spin"
    animation__xyr="property:rotation;from:0 0;to:-180 90;dur:900;dir:normal;loop:1;easing:linear;startEvents:br;"
    animation="property:position.x;from:0;to:5;dur:900;dir:normal;loop:1;easing:linear;startEvents:br;"
    animation__xyr="property:rotation;from:-180 90;to:-360 0;dur:900;dir:normal;loop:1;easing:linear;startEvents:br;"
    animation="property:position.x;from:5;to:10;dur:900;dir:normal;loop:1;easing:linear;startEvents:br;"
</a-mixin>
```

The first two steps work perfectly but the entity disappears after `animation="property:position.x;from:0;to:5...` and doesn't carry out the last two animations. How do I get it to carry out all 4 steps, it has to be triggered by one click.

I expected the entity (a plane) to complete a whole barrel roll but it stops half way through the spin. I tried writing the rotation as one animation but I don't know how to make it rotate 90 degrees in one way and the back the other on the Y-axis in the same animation.

Is there any different way I can get my plant to carry out this movement?

Comment: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089939/making-two-animations-at-once-in-a-frame) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135178/a-frame-multiple-animations-with-camera)

Answer (score -1):

{
"animation": {
"frametime": 1,
"keyframes": [
0,
{
"rotation": [0, 0, 0],
"time": 0
},
{
"rotation": [0, 360, 0],
"time": 10
},
{
"rotation": [0, 720, 0],
"time": 20
}
]
}
}